# How can I get the description,assignee name of a JIRA issue via the REST API?

Tags: java, json, jira, jira-rest-api

Normally I use java program to get the issues of the jira using jirarestapi.Now after getting that json response i am able to get the keys only.

**The json response is the following picture.**

[image]

Now by using the key i want to get the description and the assignee name of that particular jira using those keys.

Comment: Please don't post codes as pictures.

Comment: That is not the code bro.it is the json response i got  for my java code. Now i am able to get the key by passing it to an json array.and for me not only the key but also the name of the jira,description of the jira and if possible assignee name also needed. So i need preferred solution approach so that i have to get those things from this json response or i have to run the HTTP URI method once again so that i can get the description for each and every key.So i need The JQL for getting the description etc., @yassadi

Comment: @GUMMADIVIJAYAKUMAR, are you saying that the REST API response doesn't have the `description`, `assignee` fields in the response?

Comment: YEs exactly.I can't say it does not have but if it had how to get that particular field from the fields of above 2000. if it does not had then i need the JQL which exactly gives the rest response as description, assignee and name of the jira. @N00bPr0grammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The information you are looking for is in the fields part of the JSON returned. All the fields you require are jira standard fields, so they are easy to find. You need: summary, description and assignee.

To limit the amount of field returned, you can adjust your rest call. If you use the jql endpoint you can add the following to the end of your request:

```
 &fields=summary,description,assignee
```

On a unrelated note, your jira instance should really not have 2000+ custom fields. It is terrible for performance.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hey @Runningriot. thanks for you answer.  I want to upvote for taking time to solve my issue but i don't have more reputation. ok now i ahve the new issue when i follow your approach. my rest api response is giving an error as :{"errorMessages":["Field 'fields' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it."],"errors":{}} .So can you please provide me of another way to work it around

Comment: We need more information than just the error message. What is the rest call you make.

Comment: Server returned HTTP response code: 400 for URL: //jira3.cerner.com/rest/api/2/search?jql=project%20%3D%20PROJECT%20AND%20component%20%3D%20%22COMP%20comp%22%20AND%20fixVersion%20%3D FIXVERSION%20%20AND%20fields%3Ddescription  and all the capital's of PROJECT,COMP,FIXVERSION contains the companies confidential information which i can't post it here but it does not have any problem because when i add fields description then only i am getting the 400 response. other times i am getting the good response

Comment: to only display description as you are trying you need to use &fields=description and not AND fields = description

Comment: Hello @Runningriot your answer useful a lot.I need Another help.How can i get the QA name using the fields ?.I have searched a lot of documentation.but nothing helped.Could you please help me.

Comment: If my answers have helped you please upvote or accept my answer. If you have new questions please open a new question.

Comment: Yes. Your answer has helped a lot.I want to upvote for taking time to solve my issue but i don't have more reputation. i have accepted it. Thanks..

Answer (score -1):

The answer to your question is already available on the Atlassian forums but not fully, but you could still take a look at it for your implementation.

[Atlassian forum query](https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/How-to-limit-the-fields-in-the-JIRA-Rest-response/qaq-p/561379)

To provide you with a brief gist of what should be done, You could add an additional `JQL` statement to filter your REST response further.

```
&fields=description
```

You could further refer to the JIRA documentation [here](https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/?_ga=2.73063952.2073995423.1524152776-1032145406.1520649628#d2e3181)

> fields [string]
>
> Multi-value parameter defining the fields returned for the issue. By default, all fields are returned. Allowed values:
>
> - all - return all fields.
> - navigable - return navigable fields only.
> - summary,comment - return the summary and comments fields only.
> - comment - return all fields except comments.
> - all,comment - same as above

Hope this helps!

Comment: Care to provide the reason why this answer was downvoted?

Comment: Who down voted? I don't have permission to down vote or upvote(i have less reputation).  @N00bPr0grammer your answer helped and thanks a lot.

Comment: i have anotehr issue that it is showing the error and the error of my rest response is as follows : {"errorMessages":["Field 'fields' does not exist or you do not have permission to view it."],"errors":{}} .So can you please provide me of another way to work it around.@N00b Pr0grammer